# How to Check the language of any String in android app

Tags: android

How can I check if a particular word is an English word in android programmatically?

I have tried to use:

```
Locale.getdefault.getDisplayLanguage().equals()
```

Answer (score 1):

what your are trying to do is detecting language.

you can either load the entire English dictionary for offline usage, or you can use an online API to do the detecting for you.

there's quite a lot, one of which is to use the language detect function from the  Google translate API. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language